# T-SQL update table A with values from table B (hard coded)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table A, where I have 164 distinct values for column CODE as follows:

| Code |
| --- |
| May-Update-DTO |
| Terminated |
| Breaking |
| One-Two-One |
| "None" |

etc

I also have a CSV file where all of these codes above are mapped to a different values that our software understands:

May-Update-DTO --> None Shift
Terminated --> Value Time
Breaking --> None Dom
One-Two-One --> POE Exec
"None" --> Manual

I have to essentially source this CSV file and update table A per the CSV values above. I can potentially load these CSV files into a local table. What would be the best way to accomplish this? CSV file has like 250 records.

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you possibly supply some example values from the CSV file in your questoin, by clicking the [edit] link? This would allow community members to possibly answer your question. Currently your questions doesn't contain enough information. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you should upload the CSV to a table and do a typical `JOIN` and `UPDATE` statement. Maybe a screenshot of the CSV in your post would help. Currently unsure if it stores both sides of the mapping in a single column, and what the syntax is.

Comment: [dup on MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/978017/t-sql-update-table-a-with-values-from-table-b-hard.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you load your CSV into a table, you can do a simple `UPDATE` with `JOIN`

```sql
UPDATE a
SET Code = csv.NewCode
FROM TableA a
JOIN CsvTable csv ON csv.Code = a.Code;
```